# Tensorflow initialize certain scope only

Tags: python, tensorflow

He there,

I have a question regarding control over which variable scope is initialized, or at least, which variable scope is used during the run.

Take for example this easy piece of code

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

with tf.variable_scope('0') as scope:
    place_holder_batch_x = tf.Variable(np.random.rand(11,6), dtype=tf.float64)
    place_holder_batch_y = tf.Variable(np.random.rand(8,5), dtype=tf.float64)
    rnn_cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.BasicRNNCell(3)
    z = place_holder_batch_x*2

with tf.variable_scope('1') as scope:
    place_holder_batch_x = tf.Variable(np.random.rand(10,5), dtype=tf.float64)
    place_holder_batch_y = tf.Variable(np.random.rand(9,6), dtype=tf.float64)
    rnn_cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.BasicRNNCell(4)
    z = place_holder_batch_x*2

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(init)
print(sess.run(z).shape)
```

If I would run this as is, I would get the shape of variable z as is defined in variable scope '1'.
But how can I specify which variable scope to use during the session? I couldn't find any answer on stackoverflow or in the documentation...

Of course I could just rename both z's to z1 and z2... but I want to stay on the situation where both scopes look a lot like each other and use the same names...

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf


g1 = tf.Graph()
with g1.as_default() as g:
    with tf.variable_scope('0') as scope:
        place_holder_batch_x = tf.Variable(np.random.rand(11,6), dtype=tf.float64)
        place_holder_batch_y = tf.Variable(np.random.rand(8,5), dtype=tf.float64)
        rnn_cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.BasicRNNCell(3)
        z = place_holder_batch_x*2
g2 = tf.Graph()
with g2.as_default() as g:
    with tf.variable_scope('1') as scope:
        place_holder_batch_x = tf.Variable(np.random.rand(10,5), dtype=tf.float64)
        place_holder_batch_y = tf.Variable(np.random.rand(9,6), dtype=tf.float64)
        rnn_cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.BasicRNNCell(4)
        z = place_holder_batch_x*2

tf.reset_graph_default()

graph_to_be_used = g1

with tf.session(graph = graph_to_be_used) as sess:
    init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

    sess.run(init)
    print(sess.run(z).shape)
```

Comment: Cool! Thanks for the answer, will try it out tomorrow.

However, can you explain a little bit about the thought behind this as well? Because essentially we are defining twice some unique ID to the set of variables... why can't we start a session with a certain set of scope variables... or put it differently, what is the use of defining the variable scope now? Since we already have the unique graph identifier...

Comment: Wait.. thinking about it a bit longer.. I think I understand it. Because a Graph can be constructed in such a way that it contains multiple variables scopes.(e.g. which could perhaps share variables).

Then another questions pops up for me... and that is, why don't I see the usage of defining such a graph that often in code examples? Is that a bias in my view? Or is it less common to use it?

(Sorry for the amount of text btw...)